# Lantency Monitoring in Flink 1.14

Tags: apache-flink

I am following this [Flink tutorial](https://flink.apache.org/2021/05/06/reactive-mode.html) for reactive scaling and am interested in knowing how overall end-to-end latencies are affected by such rapid changes in the number of worker nodes. As per the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/config/), I have added `metrics.latency.interval: 1000` to the config map with the understanding that a new latency metric will be added with markers being sent every 1 second. However, I cannot seem to find the corresponding histogram in prometheus. Listed below are this which are available metrics associated with latency:

[image]

I am using Flink 1.14. Is there something which I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I am suspecting that something happened to the latency metric between releases 1.13.2 and 1.14. Per now, I am not able to see the latency metrics from Flink after migration to 1.14, despite setting the latency interval to a positive number. Have you tried 1.13.2?

Comment: Yes, [FLINK-22766](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-22766) Flink-1.13.2 and Flink-1.14 add metrics for kafkaSource

Answer (score 1):

.. further exploration lead me to believe it is the migration to the  KafkaSource / KafkaSink classes, as opposed to the deprecated FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer that actually made the latency metric disappear. Currently, I am seeing the latency measures on flink 1.14, however using the deprecated Kafka source / sinks..

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow.
Your answer seems to be a comment as it doesn't solve the problem. Therefore use the comment section below the question.